# Unable to debug workflow

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying debug a workflow code and it always shows that the breakpoint cannot be hit. I have made sure that I deploy the recent code.

Also I have tried to load the PDB symbols using windows->debug->modules but I don't see the dll of my project there.

I am not not understanding how to proceed further. I am using vs2010 and sharepoint 2010

Answer (score 0):

In order to debug workflows you have to attach to owstimer.exe and w3wp.exe (try all of them if there a several). And of course you have to have the same code both in studio and deployed.